# Sort Danish alphabetically using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, sorting, locale

Is there a library or cross-browser native implementation to sort an array of Danish strings alphabetically in JavaScript?

> [Aalborg, Sorø ...]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately @Tibos solution doesnt work. The danish letters `æøå` is not sortable as a dane would expect. And it certainly wont work with `aa`, which is considered as an oldschool `å`. The only solution is to make an "handheld" sort-algorithm.

Here is working solution :

```js
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    function getCode(c) {
        c=c.toLowerCase();
        if (c.substring(0,2)=='aa') return 300; 
        switch (c.charCodeAt(0)) {
            case 229 : //å
                return 299;
                break;
            case 248 : //ø
                return 298;
                break;
            case 230 : //æ
                return 297;
                break;
            default : 
                return c.charCodeAt(0);
                break;
        }
    }
    return getCode(a) - getCode(b);
});
```

The test array

```
var arr = ['Ølby', 'Ålestrup', 'Ærø', 'Almindingen', 'Aalborg', 'Sorø'];
```

is by locale sorted as

```
["Ølby", "Ærø", "Ålestrup", "Sorø", "Almindingen", "Aalborg"]
```

Which is totally wrong. The above function sort the array correct :

```
["Almindingen", "Sorø", "Ærø", "Ølby", "Ålestrup", "Aalborg"]
```

---

**Update**

@tibos was absolutely right. The above algorithm just sort by the first letter. The below function converts the strings to array of integers, according to the sorting-scheme from the algorithm above. Then it compares the integer arrays - by that, the strings are sorted in their full length  :

```js
arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    var d, e, f;
    function getIntArray(c) {
        var array=[];
        c=c.toLowerCase();
        for (var i=0;i<c.length;i++) {
            if (c.substring(i,2)=='aa') {
                array.push(300); 
                i++;
            } else {
                switch (c.charCodeAt(i)) {
                    case 229 : //å
                        array.push(299);
                        break;
                    case 248 : //ø
                        array.push(298);
                        break;
                    case 230 : //æ
                        array.push(297);
                        break;
                    default : 
                        array.push(c.charCodeAt(i));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
    d=getIntArray(a);
    e=getIntArray(b);
    for (f=0;f<d.length;f++) {
        if (d[f]!=e[f]) {
            return d[f] - e[f];
        }
    }
});
```

test array :

```
var arr = ['Ølby', 'Ålborg', 'Århus', 'Ålestrup', 'Åkikrkeby', 'Ærø', 'Almindingen', 'Aalborg', 'Sorø'];
```

is now sorted in full length :

```
["Almindingen", "Sorø", "Ærø", "Ølby", "Åkikrkeby", "Ålborg", "Ålestrup", "Århus", "Aalborg"]
```

Comment: Good answer, but you might want to expand it to support all rules listed in [this document](http://std.dkuug.dk/cultreg/registrations/narrative/da_DK,_4.3.html) (which I guess is the official standard).

Comment: You apparently know enough about the Danish language to implement a correct comparison function. It does seem that your function only looks at the first character now, but i suppose that is a slight overlook.

Comment: have made a more clean version with some options for dealing with `aa` and a test-script -> https://github.com/davidkonrad/sortda

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following method to sort strings in any language in Chrome and IE11:

```
var arr = ['Aalborg', 'Sorø']; // array to sort
var myLocale = 'da-DK'; // danish locale

var sortedArr = arr.sort(function(a,b) { return a.localeCompare(b, myLocale); }); // sort

console.log(sortedArr);
```

For a more browser agnostinc solution, you have two options:

1. shim the localeCompare function (or replace it with one only for danish)
2. change the whole sorting algorithm

For this task i would use a [bucket-sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort)-like algorithm that should in theory run faster than the default sort (it would make the minimal number of comparisons).

The general idea is that you go through each string, place them in (sorted) buckets according to the first letter. You continue to split each bucket containing at least 2 strings according to the second letter, then the third and so on. At the end you merge the buckets and you have the sorted array.

Comment: Works in Chrome only, is there a cross-browser implementation or a library? (the options arg. is not implemented in FF)

Comment: It dosent work in chrome either, at least not in my version 18.0.1025.168 on ubuntu. But +1 anyway, we should expect it to work (but there is _always_ problems with danish letters :)

Comment: @davidkonrad If you're talking about it apparently sorting them backwards, I was confused about it as well, but then i realized that it somehow considers `aa > s`. Nevermind, i don't know enough about Danish to figure out all the sorting rules.

Comment: I would have thought your solution worked also, but it seems it just consider the special letters as a's. Sorting danish letters has always been a problem, even for databases, wordprocessors and so on, so I am not surprised your good answer fail. Bet it works for french and german characters :)

Comment: Using arrow functions: `arr.sort((a,b) => a.localeCompare(b, myLocale));`